# Dropdown with selectedValue is not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am binding the dropdown list from a viewbag object. while converting the object to select list am using the 4th overload method which has list, string, string, object as param.

The selection of dropdown is not working. the 4th param of this SelectList is not working.

Here is the code:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("mylist", new SelectList(ViewBag.MyList, "Value", "Text", selectedValue: "3"));
```

ViewBag.Mylist contains a list of Values objects:

```
public class Values
{
    public string Text { set; get; }
    public string Value { set; get; }
}
```

Let me know why this overloaded method is not working? OR am i using this wrongly?

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` element to a collection of complex objects (`mylist`). Use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, new SelectList(ViewBag.MyList, "Value", "Text"))` but your use of `new SelectList()` suggests `ViewBag.MyList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectList>` it which case why are you creating an identical 2nd one? - it should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, (SelectList)ViewBag.MyList)`

Comment: You have deleted your model! What are you trying to bind to? (your currently binding to `mylist` which is typeof `List<Values>` which cannot work as I noted in my first comment)

Comment: Yes 'List<Values>' has to be converted to SelectList in view getting it from ViewBag. Then binding it to dropdown with a selection. My question is why @Html.DropDownList("mylist", new SelectList(ViewBag.MyList, "Value", "Text", selectedValue: "3")); this line is not working ? the last param is not working!!

Comment: But to what property of your model? You need a property to bind to and that property need to be a simple value type (e.g. `string`)

Comment: The last parameter is ignored because your binding to a value in `ViewData` which is `myitems` and `myitems` is `System.Collections.Generic.List[Value]` and your options do not contain a value that matches that.

Comment: If your model has a property `string SelectedItem` then its as per my first comment (and if the value of `SelectedItem = 3` the the option with `value="3"` will be selected. That's how model binding works - its binds to your property)

Comment: you mean to say i have to use List<SelectListItem> instead of List<Values>?

Comment: No. I mean you need to bind to a property in your model which is typeof `string`. Whether you create the `SelectList` in the controller (the correct way) or in the view as your doing makes no difference. Just use the code in my first comment